# Wordpress wp_is_mobile() function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I have a plugin on my Wordpress that I want to block when a user is on mobile. In my functions.php I added the line:

```
if (wp_is_mobile())
{
    wp_dequeue_script('flare');
    wp_deregister_script('flare');
}
```

Unfortunately, this made the script not load for both mobile and desktop users. So I need to figure out a way to make this script unload if they are on mobile.

I used a similar function inside my post-template, for adding regular share buttons at the bottom of the post if they were on mobile - but this also didn't work. It added the share buttons for both mobile and desktop users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you are using a caching system (WP Total Cache for example); you browsed the page from desktop (page was cached), then you browsed the same page using a device simulator (Chrome Inspector) but you see the same result. Things could be even complex if you are logged, because caching systems usually are disabled for logged users.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false
                    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
                    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
                    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
                    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
                    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false
                    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi') !== false ) {
                    //Mobile browser do stuff here       
        } else {
                    //Do stuff here
            }
```

Comment: hi @Jay Bhatt, the code you posted is very similar to [the code of the wp_is_mobile() function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/vars.php#L127); why do your code is supposed to work better? You have received 3 upvote till now so I suppose that you are right...what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hello just addition to @jay bhatt ans please check your functions.php for the filter

```
wp_is_mobile
```

code may look like

```
add_filter( 'wp_is_mobile', 'custom_detection_code', 99, 1 );
```

then think for Jay bhatt's answer

Answer (score -2):

I think Script `dequeuing` calls should be added to the `wp_print_scripts` action hook.

Scripts are normally enqueued on the `wp_enqueue_script` hook, which happens early in the `wp_head` process. The `wp_print_scripts` hook happens right before scripts are printed. So I think you should be doing as follows :

```
function deque_my_scripts () {
    wp_dequeue_script('flare');
    wp_deregister_script('flare');
}

if (wp_is_mobile())
{
   add_action('wp_print_scripts','deque_my_scripts');
}
```

You can also add the action hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts`

So another method will be

```
if (wp_is_mobile())
{
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','deque_my_scripts', 20);

}
```

Hope this helps you :-)