# wp_is_mobile() function not working in child theme wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created child theme of motion picture parent theme. what I am trying to do is redirect the page if it is mobile.

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    function mobile_home_redirect(){

        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/abc.php' );
        exit;

    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mobile_home_redirect' );

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has already answered here [enter link description here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407218/wordpress-wp-is-mobile-function-not-working

Comment: Already tried that, But also not working..                                                                                        Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use- 
  header('Location: path here ');
    exit;

Comment: wp_is_mobile() function is not working...                                                               .function mobile_home_redirect(){

    include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/abc.php' );
    exit;
} add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mobile_home_redirect' );                        .                                                                                                                        .These code works perfectly...                                                                                .Thanks for your suggestion....